# Como utilizar um retorno ajax em qualquer parte do script?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Tenho um Json que é retornado via ajax, eu queria que eu pudesse manipular esse retorno em todo o meu script, fora do escopo do Ajax, pra não ter que fazer uma função que faça tudo dentro desse escopo. Dessa forma está funcionando, mas não me parece uma boa prática.

Cod:

```
  jQuery.ajax({
        url: 'consulta.php' + location.search,
        type: "GET",
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(returnjson) {

          //Exibe os dados de primeira
          $('#id_pergunta').html(returnjson[i].id_pergunta);
          $('#pergunta_jogo').html(returnjson[i].pergunta);
          $('#desafio_jogo').html(returnjson[i].desafio);
          $('#resposta_jogo').html(returnjson[i].resposta);
          $('#equipeum').html(returnjson.equipeum);
          $('#equipedois').html(returnjson.equipedois);
          if (vez === 1){
            alert("A Equipe " + returnjson.equipeum + " iniciará o jogo");
          } else{
            alert("A Equipe " + returnjson.equipedois + " iniciará o jogo");
          }
          //troca a pergunta
          $('#proxima').click(function proxima(){
            i++;
            $('#id_pergunta').html(returnjson[i].id_pergunta);
            $('#pergunta_jogo').html(returnjson[i].pergunta);
            $('#desafio_jogo').html(returnjson[i].desafio);
            $('#resposta_jogo').html(returnjson[i].resposta);
          });
        },
        error: function(returnjson) {
            alert("Erro interno do servidor");
            window.location = 'Index.php';
        }
    });
```

Comment: A lógica é correta, tem mesmo de ser iniciado de dentro do `success`. Podes porem organizar melhor o código. Esse `'#proxima'` é carregado com o ajax ou já existe na página?

Comment: Já existe na paagina.

Answer (score 2):

Bom dia, sua pergunta é no sentido de **organização de código**, então vou sugerir um pequeno **refatoramento**, usando um modelo de código que uso nos meus projetos. O intuito é somente demonstrar algumas possibilidades que você teria, e é totalmente hipotético, visto que não conheço sua aplicação. Também como não sei seu grau de conhecimento em JavaScript, talvez eu fale o que você já sabe. Mas vamos lá.

Primeiramente, eu sugiro sempre *encapsular* de alguma forma seu código, para que você nunca (ou quase nunca) use o **escopo global**. Isto é uma boa prática em JavaScript e por mais que isto não pareça ser uma necessidade (principalmente quando o projeto é pequeno), você com certeza sentirá a necessidade disto quando a sua aplicação escalar. Além de ajudar - e muito - na manutenção e organização de código.

Uma prática bem comum (muito usada principalmente antes do surgimento dos módulos) é a famosa [**IIFE** *(Immediately Invoked Function Expression)*](http://pedrotcaraujo.github.io/2014/12/01/funcoes-imediatas-IIFE/). Sugiro usar ela aqui (se já não está usando, claro).

Outra prática que costumo adotar é ter um objeto que armazena todas as referências  dos meus objetos jQuery, assim eu não preciso ficar selecionando eles todas as vezes (ganhamos em performance também), nem repetindo os seletores toda vez que for chamá-los (muitas vezes são complexos/compridos), e se um dia eles alterarem, posso mudar um lugar só. Costumo chamar este objeto de `ui`.

E uma função `bind` que faz todos os *binds* de eventos daquele módulo (click, keyboard, mouse...). Esta função é carregada sempre no `ready` do `document` para termos certeza que tudo já foi carregado (indispensável).

No seu código, separei as funções de `success` e `error` do Ajax.

Também coloquei uma variável que armazena os dados recebidos (`questions`)  dentro do módulo, e toda vez que o ajax recebe, ele a seta (lembrando que isso foi um chute da sua estrutura).

Por fim, encapsulei em uma função só as instruções de mostrar a questão na tela (vi que estava sendo feito duas vezes, quando clicava pra ir pra próxima, e quando recebia os dados).

Ah, e também coloquei as variáveis em **inglês**. Isto é uma longa discussão sobre em que língua definir as variáveis em um projeto em PT, mas eu, ***pessoalmente***, prefiro sempre em inglês. Mas isto é apenas um detalhe.

Eis a minha sugestão completa:

```
var QuestionsManager = (function() {

    var ui = {};
    var activeQuestion = 0;
    var playerTurn = 1;
    var questions = []

    $(document).ready(function() {
        bind();
    });

    function bind() {

        ui['id_pergunta'] = $('#id_pergunta');
        ui['pergunta_jogo'] = $('#pergunta_jogo');
        ui['desafio_jogo'] = $('#desafio_jogo');
        ui['resposta_jogo'] = $('#resposta_jogo');
        ui['equipeum'] = $('#equipeum');
        ui['equipedois'] = $('#equipedois');
        ui.btn = {
            'proxima': $("#proxima")
        } 

        ui.btn['proxima'].on("click", function() {
            activeQuestion++;
            showActiveQuestion();
        });

    }

    function ajaxGetQuestions() {

        $.ajax({
            url: 'consulta.php' + location.search,
            type: "GET",
            dataType: 'json',
            success: successGetQuestions,
            error: errorGetQuestions
        });

    }


    function successGetQuestions(questionsjson) {

        questions = questionsjson;
        activeQuestion = 0;

        showActiveQuestion();

        ui['equipeum'].html(json.equipeum);
        ui['equipedois'].html(json.equipedois);
        if (playerTurn === 1){
            alert("A Equipe " + json.equipeum + " iniciará o jogo");
        } else{
            alert("A Equipe " + json.equipedois + " iniciará o jogo");
        }       
    }

    function errorGetQuestions() {
        alert("Erro interno do servidor");
        window.location = 'Index.php';      
    }

    function showActiveQuestion() {
        ui['id_pergunta'].html(questions[activeQuestion].id_pergunta);
        ui['pergunta_jogo'].html(questions[activeQuestion].pergunta);
        ui['desafio_jogo'].html(questions[activeQuestion].desafio);
        ui['resposta_jogo'].html(questions[activeQuestion].resposta);
    }

    //escolhemos o que vamos expor
    return {
        ajaxGetQuestions: getQuestions
    }

})();

/* somente uma função está disponível
  "pelo lado de fora", que é a getQuestions(), o resto
  é "privado" do "módulo" que criamos */

QuestionsManager.getQuestions(); //invoca o ajax
```

Enfim, é apenas uma sugestão para ilustrar algumas técnicas que existem. O código não foi testado.

Espero que ajude de alguma forma.